# Counting the number of consecutive occurences of numbers in dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with a dummy column that contains 1s and 0s and I would like to count for each row how many times the 1s or 0s have occurred, starting at 0 every time, and counting up for 1s and counting down for 0s I have an example below:

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.DataFrame({'Dummy': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        'Counter': [-1, -2, 1, 2, 3, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

```
blocks = df.Dummy.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
counters = df.groupby(blocks).cumcount() + 1
df['Counter'] = np.where(df['Dummy']==0, -1, 1) * counters
```

Output:

```
   Dummy  Counter
0      0       -1
1      0       -2
2      1        1
3      1        2
4      1        3
5      0       -1
6      1        1
7      1        2
8      1        3
9      1        4
```

Comment: Wow, this is extremely elegant. thank you so much for this!!!

Comment: I have posted a more complicated version of this problem that includes the requirement to group this by date and stock name here, in case you have time to look at it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64162212/counting-the-number-of-consecutive-occurences-of-numbers-in-dataframe-with-multi