# Counting the number of consecutive occurences of numbers in dataframe with multi index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that has a multi index (stock and datetime) with a dummy column that contains 1s and 0s and I would like to count for each stock and for each day, in each row how many times the 1s or 0s have occurred in the 'Dummy" column, starting at 1 every time, and counting up for 1s and counting down for 0s I have an example below where the column 'Counter' represents what I would like to create:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(  {
'stock': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL','AAPL', 'AAPL','AAPL', 'AAPL', 'MSFT', 'MSFT'], 
'datetime': ['2015-01-02 20:57', '2015-01-02 20:58', '2015-01-02 20:59', '2015-01-02 21:00','2015-01-03 20:57', '2015-01-03 20:58', '2015-01-03 20:59','2015-01-02 20:57', '2015-01-02 20:58'],
'Dummy': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1,1, 0, 1, 1],
'Counter': [-1, -2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1,2]})
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df.set_index(['stock', 'datetime'], inplace =True)
```

A simpler version of this problem was answered here (this ignores the tickers and dates however)

[Counting the number of consecutive occurences of numbers in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64128616/counting-the-number-of-consecutive-occurences-of-numbers-in-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just slightly modify your previous solution

```
m = df.Dummy.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
counters = df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0), 
                       df.index.get_level_values(1).date, 
                       m]).cumcount()+1
df['Counter'] = np.where(df['Dummy']==0, -1, 1) * counters

Out[95]:
                           Dummy  Counter
stock datetime
AAPL  2015-01-02 20:57:00      0       -1
      2015-01-02 20:58:00      0       -2
      2015-01-02 20:59:00      1        1
      2015-01-02 21:00:00      1        2
      2015-01-03 20:57:00      1        1
      2015-01-03 20:58:00      1        2
      2015-01-03 20:59:00      0       -1
MSFT  2015-01-02 20:57:00      1        1
      2015-01-02 20:58:00      1        2
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer you linked:

1. First, create a `date` column, which you need to include in the logic to create `blocks`
2. Then, just slightly modify the logic for the `blocks` series by including `| (df.day.diff().ne(0))`
3. Finally, include `stock` in the `.groupby`. You can refer to multi-index columns directly in a groupby:

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(  {
'stock': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL','AAPL', 'AAPL','AAPL', 'AAPL', 'MSFT', 'MSFT'], 
'datetime': ['2015-01-02 20:57', '2015-01-02 20:58', '2015-01-02 20:59', '2015-01-02 21:00','2015-01-03 20:57', '2015-01-03 20:58', '2015-01-03 20:59','2015-01-02 20:57', '2015-01-02 20:58'],
'Dummy': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1,1, 0, 1, 1],
'Counter': [-1, -2, 1, 2, 1, -1, 1, 1,2]})
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df['date'] = df['datetime'].dt.date
df.set_index(['stock', 'datetime'], inplace =True)
blocks = (df.Dummy.diff().ne(0) | (df['date'].ne(df['date'].shift()))).cumsum()
counters = df.groupby(['stock', blocks]).cumcount() + 1
df['Counter'] = np.where(df['Dummy']==0, -1, 1) * counters
df
Out[1]: 
                           Dummy  Counter        date
stock datetime                                       
AAPL  2015-01-02 20:57:00      0       -1  2015-01-02
      2015-01-02 20:58:00      0       -2  2015-01-02
      2015-01-02 20:59:00      1        1  2015-01-02
      2015-01-02 21:00:00      1        2  2015-01-02
      2015-01-03 20:57:00      1        1  2015-01-03
      2015-01-03 20:58:00      1        2  2015-01-03
      2015-01-03 20:59:00      0       -1  2015-01-03
MSFT  2015-01-02 20:57:00      1        1  2015-01-02
      2015-01-02 20:58:00      1        2  2015-01-02
```

Comment: Wow, I have been struggling with this since yesterday...thank you so much!!!

Comment: Would this still work if I switch to the next month though? Because you used day

Comment: @NiccolaTartaglia no problem, please upvote and / or accept as answer if helpful. I appreciate it - Thanks!

Comment: Yep, will do. I am trying to see which answer works best right now. But both of your answers have been very helpful!!!