# Counting the number of consecutive occurences of numbers in dataframe with multi index daily data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

A version of this problem was answered here (this uses data at the minute frequency however).

[Counting the number of consecutive occurences of numbers in dataframe with multi index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64162212/counting-the-number-of-consecutive-occurences-of-numbers-in-dataframe-with-multi)

I have a dataframe that has a multi index (stock ticker and date) with a dummy column that contains 1s and 0s and I would like to count for each stock, in each row how many times the 1s or 0s have occurred in the 'Dummy" column, starting at 1 every time, and counting up for 1s and counting down for 0s I have an example below where the column 'Counter' represents what I would like to create:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(  {
'stock': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL','AAPL', 'MSFT', 'MSFT','MSFT', 'MSFT'], 
'datetime': ['2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-05', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-05'],
'Dummy': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1,1, 0, 1],
'Counter': [-1, -2, 1, 2, 1, 2, -1, 1]})
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df.set_index(['stock', 'datetime'], inplace =True)
```

Comment: For MSFT - 2015-01-04 - 0(Dummy), the Counter should be 1 or -1?

Comment: You are correct, it should be -1, I fixed it.

Comment: @NiccolaTartaglia Can you please explain why the value of `Counter` for the symbol `MSFT` on `2015-01-04` is `-1`, i think this should be instead `1`?

Comment: It's because the Dummy is 0, so that is first 0 for MSFT after it was positive before. That's why it should be -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'stock': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL',
              'MSFT', 'MSFT', 'MSFT', 'MSFT'],
    'datetime': ['2015-01-02', '2015-01-03',
                 '2015-01-04', '2015-01-05',
                 '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03',
                 '2015-01-04', '2015-01-05'],
    'Dummy': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]})
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df.set_index(['stock', 'datetime'], inplace=True)

# Group Consecutive 1 and 0 groups in each stock together
df['group'] = df.groupby('stock')['Dummy'] \
    .transform(lambda g: g.ne(g.shift()).cumsum())
# Set Value Placeholder in Counter 1 -> 1, 0 -> -1
df['Counter'] = df['Dummy'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 1 else -1)
# Get cumsum from each stock and group
df['Counter'] = df.groupby(['stock', 'group'])['Counter'].cumsum().astype(int)
# Drop Group Column
df = df.drop(columns='group')

# For Display
print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
                  Dummy  Counter
stock datetime                  
AAPL  2015-01-02      0       -1
      2015-01-03      0       -2
      2015-01-04      1        1
      2015-01-05      1        2
MSFT  2015-01-02      1        1
      2015-01-03      1        2
      2015-01-04      0       -1
      2015-01-05      1        1
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use boolean masking with `cumsum` to identify the blocks of consecutive rows where the value in the `Dummy` column stays the same, then mask the `0` in `Dummy` column with `-1` followed by `groupby` and `cumsum` to calculate `Counter`

```
s = df['Dummy']
m = s.ne(s.shift())
df['Counter'] = s.mask(s.eq(0), -1).groupby(['stock', m.cumsum()]).cumsum()
```

---

```
                  Dummy  Counter
stock datetime                  
AAPL  2015-01-02      0       -1
      2015-01-03      0       -2
      2015-01-04      1        1
      2015-01-05      1        2
MSFT  2015-01-02      1        1
      2015-01-03      1        2
      2015-01-04      0       -1
      2015-01-05      1        1
```

Comment: Thank you. So this worked for the dataframe example I provided but somehow it doesn't work on my actual dataframe. I am trying to find out why, something minor seems to be different.

Comment: @NiccolaTartaglia IMO this should work fine but Can you please edit your question with some sample rows where you are getting different results?

Comment: I agree, and it does work perfectly fine in the example I gave above. I am trying to find what exactly is different in my actual dataframe, there seems to be some minor difference somewhere.

Comment: @NiccolaTartaglia Are you sure your dummy column only contains `0's` and `1's`? May be you can try replacing the condition `s.mask(s.eq(0), -1)` with `s.mask(s.ne(1), -1)`

Comment: very elegant. it seems like `mask()` is an inverted `where()`, is that right?

Comment: Thanks @tdy Exactly, not much of a difference between `mask` and `where`, `mask` replaces the values where the condition holds `True` while `where` replaces the values where the condition holds `False`

Comment: So the issues is, that the count is not increasing (again, it works perfectly in the example dataframe above) in my dataframe (which is similar, that is same colums for stocks and date (which according to df.info is the same format). So I am getting just a few 1s of -1s but the count is not increasing.

Comment: For some reason the approach by Henry works on my example dataframe and my actual dataframe.

Comment: @NiccolaTartaglia have you tried replacing `s.mask(s.eq(0), -1)` with `.mask(s.ne(1), -1)`?

Comment: I will try. My dummy variable is the same though, just 1s and 0. I don't have -1 in there.

Comment: So that results to -1s and 0s instead of 1s and -1s. But still it is not increasing the count.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your contributions. So both, Henry's an Shubham's solution work on the example dataframe I posted above, but on my actual dataframe only Henry's works as expected, Shubham's approach yields just 1s and -1s but they are not increasing. I have also tried the following based on the solutions in the previous post that linked above, which also only works on the example dataframe but not on my actual dataframe (same problem where the 1's and -1s are not increasing):

```
m = df.dummy.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
counters = df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0),  
                   m]).cumcount()+1
df['Counter'] = np.where(df['dummy']==0, -1, 1) * counters
```

So I must have made some mistake with the example dataframe, which seems to be somehow different than my actual dataframe. I will try to figure out and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what the problem is. My dataframe example above is different from my actual dataframe because my actual dataframe is sorted differently. That is, it is not grouped by stocks but rather by days, so it looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(  {
'stock': ['AAPL', 'MSFT','AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AAPL', 'MSFT','AAPL', 'MSFT', ], 
'datetime': ['2015-01-02', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-05', '2015-01-05'],
'Dummy': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1,1, 0, 1],
'Counter': [-1, -2, 1, 2, 1, 2, -1, 1]})
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df.set_index(['stock', 'datetime'], inplace =True)
```

That's why Henry's solution worked on both, whereas Shubham's solution only worked on the example I provided in the original post.