# Computing the conditional probability based on consecutive occurences of numbers in dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that has a multi index (stock ticker and date) with a column that counts for each stock, in each row how many times the 1s or 0s have occurred in the 'Dummy" column. I have an example below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(  {
'stock': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL','AAPL', 'MSFT', 'MSFT','MSFT', 'MSFT'], 
'datetime': ['2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-05', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-05'],
'Dummy': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1,1, 0, 1],
'Counter': [-1, -2, 1, 2, 1, 2, -1, 1]})
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df.set_index(['stock', 'datetime'], inplace =True)
```

I would like to compute a conditional probability (for each number), that answer this question:

**Given that I observe a row with a 1 in the Counter column, how many times was it followed by a 2, and how many times was it followed by -1.**

In the example above there are 3 instances of 1s. The last one is not followed by anything so it should be ignored, so technically have only 2 instances. Both of them are followed by 2, so the output for 1 should look sth like this:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(  {
'cond prob': ['1', '2', '-1','-2'],
'1': [0, 2, 0,0],
'2': [0, 0, 1,0],
'-1': [1, 0, 0, 1],
'-2': [1, 0, 0, 0]})

 result.set_index(['cond prob',], inplace =True)
```

Basically, I would like to know for each number, how many times  it was
followed by any of the other numbers (grouped by stock).

This problem is a follow up question related to this post:

[Counting the number of consecutive occurences of numbers in dataframe with multi index daily data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67352869/counting-the-number-of-consecutive-occurences-of-numbers-in-dataframe-with-multi)

Comment: Please edit your question and include the expected output.

Comment: Will edit it and add an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `groupby` and `shift` the `Counter` column then using `crosstab` create a frequency table to count the number of times when a certain number is followed by other number

```
table = pd.crosstab(df['Counter'], df.groupby(level=0)['Counter'].shift(-1))
```

---

```
>>> table

Counter  -2.0  -1.0   1.0   2.0
Counter                        
-2          0     0     1     0
-1          1     0     1     0
 1          0     0     0     2
 2          0     1     0     0
```

If you also need to calculate probabilities we can do so by first calculating the total possible outcomes using `values_counts` then dividing favourable outcomes by all possible outcomes

```
probs = table.div(df['Counter'].value_counts(), axis=0)
```

---

```
>>> probs

Counter  -2.0  -1.0   1.0       2.0
-2        0.0   0.0   1.0  0.000000
-1        0.5   0.0   0.5  0.000000
 1        0.0   0.0   0.0  0.666667
 2        0.0   0.5   0.0  0.000000
```

Comment: Wow, this is very elegant!!! Thank you so much Shubham!!! I have a lot to learn.

Comment: @NiccolaTartaglia Pleased to help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a built in way in pandas to do that, but using plain python, it would look something like this:
\

```
two_counter, negative_counter = 0, 0

for idx, value in enumerate(df['Counter'].values):
    if idx == len(df) - 1:
        continue
    if value == 1:
        if df.iloc[idx+1, 1] == 2:
            two_counter += 1
        if df.iloc[idx+1, 1] == -1:
            negative_counter += 1
```

Comment: Yea, this works, very nice!! Thank you so much Kushim.

Comment: Happy to help :) @NiccolaTartaglia